# How do I control drag speed of Unity's scroll view to make it slower than mouse drag?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I'm having an issue figuring out how to make the scroll move slower than very fast mouse drags/swipes.

I've tried changing the scroll sensitivity, inertia deceleration rate, and the EventSystem's drag threshold value but none of these things make the scroll move slower: https://i.gyazo.com/26b339f4193013da7f2b65aaf1c72dc0.mp4

How do I change it so that when I drag the scroll bar, it only moves a fraction of the speed that I drag or even better, make a cap so that the scroll doesn't move faster than a given velocity?

Comment: A scroll bar following the mouse movement exactly is what a user would typically expect from such a widget. It sounds like what you want is not a standard scroll view at all, but a custom UI widget specific to your game. Hacking a scroll view to behave this way might not be the best route to that goal. Can you describe what you're using this to achieve? With that detail, users may be able to suggest how to make a custom widget that achieves that goal directly.